# How can I run two different react apps by just one npm start

Tags: reactjs, json, npm

so, i have two paths
React Apps:
-my-first-app
-my-second-app
is it possible to start them by just one npm start
because now i need to create two different powershells by the path of current app
i tried to wrap them into another react-app with follow package.json
"start": "cd Projects/Project1 && export PORT=3001 & cd ../Project2 && export PORT=3000 & react-scripts start",
but it's doesn't work